# divs on new lines

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
#scale div {
    float: left;
    width: 75px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 0px #333 solid;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="font-size: 10px;" id="scale">
    <div id="box" align="center" style="background:#88ff88;" >&nbsp</div>
    <div id="a">&nbsp1 &nbsp&nbsp</div>
    <div id="box" align="center" style="background:#ff8888;">&nbsp</div>
    <div id="b">&nbsp2 &nbsp&nbsp</div>
    <div id="box" align="center" style="background:#ff88ff;">&nbsp</div>
    <div id="c">&nbsp3 &nbsp&nbsp</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get the above on three lines. That is, a color block and a number on a single line.

Comment: Use `class="box"`, not an `id` (an `id` ***must*** be unique within the document).

Comment: Is your HTML code valid in http://validator.w3.org ? No? Then it's your first candidate for debugging ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have multiple elements with the same ID. It doesn't work like that. ID is unique, multiple elements can have the same class.

Second, I would recommend just having an empty span tag inside a div for your box. Divs display block by default (take up whole line) so you can have an inline-block span (takes up only required space but treated like block element) with set width and height and a number next to it.

Also, inline styles make the code look messy and difficult to read & work with. You should keep your CSS separate from your HTML.

```
<div id="scale">
  <div id="a"><span></span>1</div>
  <div id="b"><span></span>1</div>
  <div id="c"><span></span>1</div>
</div>

#scale div span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#a span{
  background-color:#00F;
}

#b span{
  background-color:#0F0;
}

#c span{
  background-color:#F00;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ewimox/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

In your `style` tag, use `display: inline-block` on all of your box divs.